# JMS publish rate is slow in SunOS

Tags: java, jms, sunos

I have a application that uses **JMS** as messaging system.

If **publisher, subscriber and weblogic** server is on *Linux*, publish rate is good enough(>30 messages/second).

But if all the three are on *SunOS*, publish rate comes down to **2-3 messages/second**.

I tried to search internet but had no luck.

Is there any know issue about that? What can be the reason of this strange behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where the issue was in logs :

> Unable to load performance pack. Using Java I/O instead. Please ensure that a native performance library is in:

Weblogic has his problem on SunOS, when 32-bit machine has 64-bin weblogic or vice versa.

Changing mode of weblogic resolved the issue.

Still to understand what is this **performance pack.**

[Explaination](http://weblogic.middlewarebase.com/2013/04/unable-to-load-performance-pack-using.html)